# Visual Studio Community 2015 adding a reference to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that requires a `System.Web.Helpers.dll Version=3.0.0.0`. But when I click in the solution explorer `Add reference` and start search for 
`System.Web.Helpers` there are two versions on this library.

- Version=1.0.0.0
- Version=2.0.0.0

But where is **3.0.0.0**. If I open the windows explorer and search for this version I found this library in different locations with **3.0.0.0** version. Why Visual Studio can't find this version?

(I don't want to use browse button)
Already tried to change targeting .NET version of the project from 4.5 to 4.5.2, to 4.6, to 4.6.1 - same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is shipped as a nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/). Add it to your project using the nuget package manager.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution for missing `System.Web.Helpers.dll Version=3.0.0.0` I though it's build-in with visual studio 2015. It was confusing for me that I should install package named `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers` to have `System.Web.Helpers.dll` because there are other assemblies name starts with `Microsoft` like: Microsoft.IdentityModel

Comment: I understand your confusion. Fortunatly this will be gone with ASP.NET Core since all depencies will come as packages.